# How do i restrict the size of display the camera shows in a-frame WebVr

Tags: aframe, webvr, skybox

I have 2 questions in A-Frame

First is
In A-frame suppose i have a camera and i want it to show only a certain dimension for example 1366x768 or 700*700 how can i achieve that?

I have attached a camera to a entity tag

```
<a-entity>
<a-camera><a-camera>
</a-entity>
```

Second is ,Is it possible to move the sky box with the camera so that i am always looking at the same location in the skybox?

Comment: You should ask just one question per post. You can move the second question to a separate post.

Comment: Ah ok thank you for letting me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the embedded component and style the canvas with CSS. This doesn't have anything to do with the camera, it's just the size of the canvas.

```
<a-scene embedded>...</a-scene>

a-scene {
  width: 50%;
}
```